# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' - Apache

Tags: php

Can anyone help me resolve this error?
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['

```
if (!function_exists('mssql_get_last_message')) {
    function mssql_get_last_message()
    {
        preg_match('/^\[Microsoft.*SQL.*Server\](.*)$/i', sqlsrv_errors(SQLSRV_ERR_ALL)[0]['message'], $matches);
        return $matches[1];
    }
}
```

Thanks

When trying to fix this other error appears
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ARRAY

Comment: What is the full and exact error message, and where is the error pointing to? I don't see anything that would cause that error.

Comment: Also, what version of PHP are you using?

Comment: https://3v4l.org/L5L2c seems to imply you're trying to run this in PHP 5.3 or lower. PHP 5.3 is about 15 years old at this point

Comment: PHP 5.2.3,.Code is really old.

Comment: Dereferencing an array element directly from a function call (e.g., `foo()[0]`) was not introduced until 5.4. You'll have to assign `sqlsrv_errors(SQLSRV_ERR_ALL)` to a variable first.